# Extend Laravel package

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, package, extend

I've searched around and couldn't find a definitive answer for this...

I have a package DevDojo Chatter and would like to extend it using my application. I understand I'd have to override the functions so that a composer update doesn't overwrite my changes.

How do I go about doing this?

**UPDATE**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->request->add(['body_content' => strip_tags($request->body)]);

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'title'               => 'required|min:5|max:255',
        'body_content'        => 'required|min:10',
        'chatter_category_id' => 'required',
    ]);

    Event::fire(new ChatterBeforeNewDiscussion($request, $validator));
    if (function_exists('chatter_before_new_discussion')) {
        chatter_before_new_discussion($request, $validator);
    }

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    }

    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;

    if (config('chatter.security.limit_time_between_posts')) {
        if ($this->notEnoughTimeBetweenDiscussion()) {
            $minute_copy = (config('chatter.security.time_between_posts') == 1) ? ' minute' : ' minutes';
            $chatter_alert = [
                'chatter_alert_type' => 'danger',
                'chatter_alert'      => 'In order to prevent spam, please allow at least '.config('chatter.security.time_between_posts').$minute_copy.' in between submitting content.',
                ];

            return redirect('/'.config('chatter.routes.home'))->with($chatter_alert)->withInput();
        }
    }

    // *** Let's gaurantee that we always have a generic slug *** //
    $slug = str_slug($request->title, '-');

    $discussion_exists = Models::discussion()->where('slug', '=', $slug)->first();
    $incrementer = 1;
    $new_slug = $slug;
    while (isset($discussion_exists->id)) {
        $new_slug = $slug.'-'.$incrementer;
        $discussion_exists = Models::discussion()->where('slug', '=', $new_slug)->first();
        $incrementer += 1;
    }

    if ($slug != $new_slug) {
        $slug = $new_slug;
    }

    $new_discussion = [
        'title'               => $request->title,
        'chatter_category_id' => $request->chatter_category_id,
        'user_id'             => $user_id,
        'slug'                => $slug,
        'color'               => $request->color,
        ];

    $category = Models::category()->find($request->chatter_category_id);
    if (!isset($category->slug)) {
        $category = Models::category()->first();
    }

    $discussion = Models::discussion()->create($new_discussion);

    $new_post = [
        'chatter_discussion_id' => $discussion->id,
        'user_id'               => $user_id,
        'body'                  => $request->body,
        ];

    if (config('chatter.editor') == 'simplemde'):
       $new_post['markdown'] = 1;
    endif;

    // add the user to automatically be notified when new posts are submitted
    $discussion->users()->attach($user_id);

    $post = Models::post()->create($new_post);


    if ($post->id) {
        Event::fire(new ChatterAfterNewDiscussion($request));
        if (function_exists('chatter_after_new_discussion')) {
            chatter_after_new_discussion($request);
        }

        if($discussion->status === 1) {
            $chatter_alert = [
                'chatter_alert_type' => 'success',
                'chatter_alert'      => 'Successfully created a new '.config('chatter.titles.discussion').'.',
            ];
            return redirect('/'.config('chatter.routes.home').'/'.config('chatter.routes.discussion').'/'.$category->slug.'/'.$slug)->with($chatter_alert);
        } else {
            $chatter_alert = [
                'chatter_alert_type' => 'info',
                'chatter_alert'      => 'You post has been submitted for approval.',
            ];
            return redirect()->back()->with($chatter_alert);
        }

    } else {
        $chatter_alert = [
            'chatter_alert_type' => 'danger',
            'chatter_alert'      => 'Whoops :( There seems to be a problem creating your '.config('chatter.titles.discussion').'.',
            ];

        return redirect('/'.config('chatter.routes.home').'/'.config('chatter.routes.discussion').'/'.$category->slug.'/'.$slug)->with($chatter_alert);
    }
}
```

There's a store function within the vendor package that i'd like to modify/override. I want to be able to modify some of the function or perhaps part of it if needed. Please someone point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean modify class implementation in your application you can change the way class is resolved:

```
app()->bind(PackageClass:class, YourCustomClass::class);
```

and now you can create this custom class like so:

```
class YourCustomClass extends PackageClass
{
   public function packageClassYouWantToChange()
   {
       // here you can modify behavior
   }
}
```

I would advise you to read more about [binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/container#binding).

Of course a lot depends on how class is created, if it is created using `new` operator you might need to change multiple classes but if it's injected it should be enough to change this single class.

Comment: This really didn't help much. I tried this and it didn't work.